# Remove parts of the URL mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this URLs:

```
mysite.com/index.php?id=que-ofrecemos
mysite.com/index.php?id=quienes-somos
```

And I want to make it look like this:

```
mysite.com/que-ofrecemos
mysite.com/quienes-somos
```

In fact, I want to remove `index.php?id=` only from URLs who have `id` set.

Comment: You are misunderstanding how mod_rewrite works. It cannot remove parts from a real URL to produce a pretty URL. Instead you must write rules which convert a pretty URL (as typed by visitors to your site) and add or adjust it into a real URL. So the question to you is: do you want every request for mysite.com/something to be modified in the background into a request for mysite.com/index.php?id=something or are there exceptions which must not be rewritten like this?

Comment: there are exceptions, I want to be "modified into a request' like you say just when `id=` is set

Comment: But the pretty URL sent by the visitor will never include `id=` so there is no rule that you can create which can check this. Instead you need to think about rules which can be checked against the pretty URLs typed by users.

Comment: @pedritoalfonso please clarify your question. What URL will be used in the browser? `index.php?id=que-ofrecemos` or `/que-ofrecemos`? Or will both be used?

Comment: the second one, the first one is the one which is in the link

Answer (score 0):

If you want your URL's to look like this in the browser

```
mysite.com/que-ofrecemos
mysite.com/quienes-somos
```

Then you need to use a rule like this. This will also redirect any URL with the id query string back to this `mysite.com/quienes-somos`. Try these rules.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php?id=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule .* /%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```